Concatenate dropdown list items in a different cell of Google Sheets
How can I concatenate dropdown list items in a different cell in Google Sheets?
For instance: I have a dropdown list in cell A2 with the following items:

Apple
Melon
Banana
Mango

I want to put, in cell B2, separated by commas, the items I selected. If I choose "Apple", them it puts "Apple" on cell B2. Then, if I choose "Banana", it puts "Banana" in cell B2 and it should look like "Apple, Banana". Is there any way of doing it?

Here's a relatively simple solution using
Ghost Values
Update values inside the LET function as appropriate - notice that B2:B3 are merged to exploit an unstable feature that avoids Circular Dependency errors
